# how to update two models with a serializer update function

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have teacher and conversation models in my project and a rate function that is a POST API with teacherId and rate as input. Teachers have phone field as an ID. When the rate function called, the teacher's rate and raters fields and the conversation's isRated field must change.
how is it possible to update two models in one serializer?

here is my Conversation model:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
   isRated = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
```

here is my Teacher model:

```
class TeacherUsers(models.Model):
     phone = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, default=0)
     rate = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
     raters = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, default=0)
```

and the serializer that updates teacher's rate only:

```
class RateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    teacherId = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    rate = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.rate = validated_data['rate']
        instance.raters = validated_data['raters']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: `phone field as an ID` phone is a private data, phone number owner can change, so this was a bad idea initially. `how is it possible to update` - by writing appropriate commands in python language. See any discussion about _"writable nested serializer"_.

Comment: phone is userName because the sms services used as authentication and also it used in other parts so the user must provide it.
like a normal serializer but inside the RateSerializer?

Comment: `so the user must provide it` this means nothing in sense of db design and private data handling. "Must provide" - `null=False`, "no overlaps" - `unique=True`. PK values will spread all over the database via FK.

Comment: I can't understand this conversation. I'll be more happy if you help me than commenting my code.

Comment: See first comment. Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I use two serializers

Comment: Update your question with new code and the issue if any.